# Ошибка в Revel framework

Tags: golang

Решил попробовать `revel` и столкнулся с ошибкой при запуске бинарника:

> "Failed to import  with error: import "": invalid import path"

Проект собрал командой `revel package`, фреймворк только установил и код не писал, если запускаю sh из архива то все работает.

Comment: Он и должен запускаться батником или sh.

Comment: Проблема в ошибке "Failed to import with error: import "": invalid import path"

Comment: просто откройте скрипт и посмотрите. Все "import path" передаются исполняемому файлу - без них он работать не будет. И эту обязанность на себя берёт скрипт. И с чего Вы, господин, взяли, что можно вот так вот просто запускать бинарник? А скрипты тогда просто для массовки?